# How to understand SUBCKT LTSPICE in order to modify an existing IGBT model to another from the same company

Tags: power-electronics, ltspice, igbt, model, subcircuit

I am struggling trying to understand how a IGBT IKW15N120BH6 is implemented through a SUBCKT. The text file  includes SUBCKT with functions  and parameters, but it is not a typical construction of a subcircuit. It is more complex. I tried to understand where this numbers comes looking into the datasheet  but no success. As many know, INFINEON does not provide anymore ltspice models of their IGBTS, and i would like to have the model of the FF150R12RT4 which i dont find anywhere. For this reason i was trying to adapt the subcircuit code of the  IKW15N120BH6 into FF150R12RT4  but without success. Any help???  Thank you in advance!

I let you the subckt code:

````
.SUBCKT IKW15N120BH6 C G E PARAMS: TJ= {TEMP}
X0OJK C G E E2 Z0BIG PARAMS: TJ= {TJ}
X0P7Z E C Z09RO PARAMS: TJ= {TJ}
.ENDS
 
.SUBCKT Z01QC N2P16 C PARAMS: TJ= {TEMP} N2Q22=298.15 N2Q6O=0.2
.PARAM N2QVM=3.60668373230914
.PARAM N2RKR= {N2Q6O*N2S9D*EXP((((TJ+273.15)/N2Q22)-1)*N2WU4)}
+N2S9D=0.000603313657579044 N2WU4=10.9307726494302
.PARAM N2X0Z= {(N2X9Y+N2Z0D*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22))/N2Q6O}
+N2X9Y=0.0025700385908055 N2Z0D=4.43576102799644E-06
.PARAM N30GC= {(N30QS+N31QY*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22))/N2Q6O}
+N30QS=0.000966825320819587 N31QY=3.88024630753137E-06
.PARAM N335J= {N36D1+N374S*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N36D1=2.60453418499801
+N374S=0.00708074620017499
.PARAM N3A5Q= {N3AD5+N3AXM*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N3AD5=2.60060925997992E-07
+N3AXM=1.52554131558009E-09
.PARAM N3B93= {N3DAA+N3DKM*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N3DAA=5.15158941987795E-07
+N3DKM=1.02039838243071E-09
X182M N2P16 C Z0MCW PARAMS: TJ= {TJ} N2Q22= {N2Q22} N2Q6O= {N2Q6O} N2QVM= {N2QVM}
+N2RKR= {N2RKR} N2X0Z= {N2X0Z} N30GC= {N30GC} N335J= {N335J} N3A5Q= {N3A5Q}
+N3B93= {N3B93}
.ENDS
 
.SUBCKT Z0413 C G E E2 PARAMS: TJ= {TEMP} N2Q22=298.15 N3DMO=0.5167
.FUNC N3EZ7(N3FD9) {IF(N3FD9>=0,IF(N3FD9>50,(N3FD9-49)*EXP(50),EXP(N3FD9))
+,IF(ABS(N3FD9)>50,1/((ABS(N3FD9)-49)*EXP(50)),1/EXP(ABS(N3FD9))))}
.FUNC N3FZZ(N3HJN,N3HN7,N3IH2,N3J2Z) {N3HN7+N3IH2*N3EZ7(N3J2Z*N3HJN)}
.PARAM KP= {N3DMO*N3J3P*PWR((TJ+273.15)/N2Q22,-1.5)} N3J3P=98.7810778478883
.PARAM N3PK5= {N3PX3+N3QEY*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N3PX3=6.47329575764793 N3QEY=
+-0.00781354774521387
.PARAM N3RWU=5.7566861716549E-05
.PARAM N3TFE=4.0935874798319
.PARAM IS= {N3DMO*N3VRD*EXP((((TJ+273.15)/N2Q22)-1)*N3WF6)}
+N3VRD=0.000966948016268587 N3WF6=7.39625886709215
.PARAM N3WZE= {N3Z19+N3ZCX*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N3Z19=0.00631847374040237
+N3ZCX=4.55483203265412E-05
.PARAM N40OC= {N4585+N4A1X*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N4585=-7.16922579234782E-06
+N4A1X=6.43953581968872E-07
.PARAM N4A6Y= {N4DS3+N4IED*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N4DS3=-2.96708195955637E-05
+N4IED=-8.6489116887711E-07
.PARAM N4JBQ=19.4479273833262
.PARAM N4JCV= {N4M0Q+N4M8G*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N4M0Q=0.0116187328249739 N4M8G=
+-3.83166993911533E-05
.PARAM N4O9U= {N4OJQ+N4OUJ*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N4OJQ=-49.8776420731124 N4OUJ=
+-0.73129860071806
.PARAM N4Q8J= {N4QGJ+N4RHB*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N4QGJ=-0.831961004786174 N4RHB=
+-0.000245188800682144
.PARAM N4SVH= {N4VI8+N4X8H*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N4VI8=4.93379590412308
+N4X8H=0.0065893749710528
.PARAM N4XP2= {N532T+N53BY*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N532T=0 N53BY=0
.PARAM N53NW= {N54AA+N55C1*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N54AA=0 N55C1=0
.PARAM N55SX=6.7821016202891
.PARAM N57ZV=12.9883435621977
.PARAM N5AYG= {IF(N3FZZ(N57ZV,N4JCV,N4O9U,N4Q8J)>N3FZZ
+(N55SX,N4JCV,N4O9U,N4Q8J),N55SX,N57ZV)}
.PARAM N5B8N= {IF(N3FZZ(N57ZV,N4JCV,N4O9U,N4Q8J)>N3FZZ
+(N55SX,N4JCV,N4O9U,N4Q8J),N57ZV,N55SX)}
.PARAM N5BBA= {IF(N3FZZ(N57ZV,N4SVH,N4XP2,N53NW)>N3FZZ
+(N55SX,N4SVH,N4XP2,N53NW),N55SX,N57ZV)}
.PARAM N5CX8= {IF(N3FZZ(N57ZV,N4SVH,N4XP2,N53NW)>N3FZZ
+(N55SX,N4SVH,N4XP2,N53NW),N57ZV,N55SX)}
.PARAM N5G0G=1; 1==N5GVE N5H87,0==N5IP9 N5H87
.PARAM N5JG4=0; 1==N5KAP(N5KRE),0==N5KAP
.PARAM N5KAP= {N3DMO*N5L86} N5L86=9.01416276576413E-09
.PARAM N5LRV=1E-08
.PARAM N5LZX=0.0
.PARAM N5OHV= {N3DMO*N5P5D} N5P5D=5.61130968083567E-08
.PARAM N5QTE= {N3DMO*N5QX9} N5QX9=1.80863206632565E-09
.PARAM N5U1H=0.101907416987955
.PARAM N5VOW=-0.440246257131178
.PARAM N6083=7.36849137370235E-10
.PARAM N61QP= {N3DMO*N62LV} N62LV=3.66704457031915E-09
.PARAM N63FK=3.93599007585238
.PARAM N63YW=-0.821650634424824
.PARAM N64FJ= {N6528+N676G*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N6528=3.7621480043751E-11
+N676G=4.84917131759226E-10
.PARAM N67W6=0.819954360322076
.PARAM N6F1G=8.38465973063364E-09
.PARAM N6FLP=1E-10
.PARAM N6GH0= {N6JK1+N6R8Z*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N6JK1=2.66302763002457
+N6R8Z=0.0144704826866174
X1BKQ C G E E2 Z0LRC PARAMS: TJ= {TJ} N2Q22= {N2Q22} N3DMO= {N3DMO} KP= {KP}
+N3RWU= {N3RWU} N3TFE= {N3TFE} IS= {IS} N5KAP= {N5KAP} N5OHV= {N5OHV} N6083= {N6083}
+N6F1G= {N6F1G}
+N6FLP= {N6FLP} N6GH0= {N6GH0} N3WZE= {N3WZE} N40OC= {N40OC} N4A6Y= {N4A6Y}
+N4JCV= {N4JCV} N4O9U= {N4O9U} N4Q8J= {N4Q8J} N4SVH= {N4SVH} N4XP2= {N4XP2}
+N53NW= {N53NW} N5QTE= {N5QTE} N5U1H= {N5U1H} N5VOW= {N5VOW} N61QP= {N61QP}
+N63FK= {N63FK} N63YW= {N63YW} N64FJ= {N64FJ} N3PK5= {N3PK5} N67W6= {N67W6}
+N5LRV= {N5LRV} N5LZX= {N5LZX} N3PX3= {N3PX3} N3QEY= {N3QEY} N4JBQ= {N4JBQ}
+N5AYG= {N5AYG}
+N5B8N= {N5B8N} N5BBA= {N5BBA} N5CX8= {N5CX8} N5G0G= {N5G0G} N5JG4= {N5JG4}
.ENDS
 
.SUBCKT Z09RO N2P16 C PARAMS: TJ= {TEMP} N2Q22=298.15 N2Q6O=0.018
.PARAM N2QVM=4.15225482990024
.PARAM N2RKR= {N2Q6O*N2S9D*EXP((((TJ+273.15)/N2Q22)-1)*N2WU4)}
+N2S9D=0.000999999996383589 N2WU4=9.68480469739453
.PARAM N2X0Z= {(N2X9Y+N2Z0D*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22))/N2Q6O}
+N2X9Y=0.00159761240379349 N2Z0D=1.56563120705306E-06
.PARAM N30GC= {(N30QS+N31QY*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22))/N2Q6O}
+N30QS=0.000439628393840198 N31QY=1.00000000950565E-08
.PARAM N335J= {N36D1+N374S*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N36D1=2.78717774182276
+N374S=1.00000046510839E-05
.PARAM N3A5Q= {N3AD5+N3AXM*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N3AD5=1.70417250407861E-07
+N3AXM=8.54745708847749E-10
.PARAM N3B93= {N3DAA+N3DKM*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N3DAA=2.45456771869468E-07
+N3DKM=6.09901718263912E-10
X182M N2P16 C Z0MCW PARAMS: TJ= {TJ} N2Q22= {N2Q22} N2Q6O= {N2Q6O} N2QVM= {N2QVM}
+N2RKR= {N2RKR} N2X0Z= {N2X0Z} N30GC= {N30GC} N335J= {N335J} N3A5Q= {N3A5Q}
+N3B93= {N3B93}
.ENDS
 
.SUBCKT Z0BIG C G E E2 PARAMS: TJ= {TEMP} N2Q22=298.15 N3DMO=0.0842
.FUNC N3EZ7(N3FD9) {IF(N3FD9>=0,IF(N3FD9>50,(N3FD9-49)*EXP(50),EXP(N3FD9))
+,IF(ABS(N3FD9)>50,1/((ABS(N3FD9)-49)*EXP(50)),1/EXP(ABS(N3FD9))))}
.FUNC N3FZZ(N3HJN,N3HN7,N3IH2,N3J2Z) {N3HN7+N3IH2*N3EZ7(N3J2Z*N3HJN)}
.PARAM KP= {N3DMO*N3J3P*PWR((TJ+273.15)/N2Q22,-1.5)} N3J3P=169.135798126506
.PARAM N3PK5= {N3PX3+N3QEY*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N3PX3=6.7391263781421 N3QEY=
+-0.00659778689402461
.PARAM N3RWU=1.21003257870887E-06
.PARAM N3TFE=3.26223918501132
.PARAM IS= {N3DMO*N3VRD*EXP((((TJ+273.15)/N2Q22)-1)*N3WF6)}
+N3VRD=0.000115518753035612 N3WF6=9.1671243694214
.PARAM N3WZE= {N3Z19+N3ZCX*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N3Z19=0.051893797491989
+N3ZCX=0.000119444395309789
.PARAM N40OC= {N4585+N4A1X*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N4585=9.96294146657158E-05
+N4A1X=9.62886091661694E-07
.PARAM N4A6Y= {N4DS3+N4IED*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N4DS3=-7.29527240303036E-05
+N4IED=4.23101901826024E-07
.PARAM N4JBQ=10.5906747475923
.PARAM N4JCV= {N4M0Q+N4M8G*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N4M0Q=0.0248795368587245
+N4M8G=5.53833603311052E-05
.PARAM N4O9U= {N4OJQ+N4OUJ*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N4OJQ=60.7291487240888 N4OUJ=
+-0.889551322025939
.PARAM N4Q8J= {N4QGJ+N4RHB*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N4QGJ=-0.984591389098398
+N4RHB=0.0014274745510032
.PARAM N4SVH= {N4VI8+N4X8H*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N4VI8=1.75240957842173
+N4X8H=0.00755091069391702
.PARAM N4XP2= {N532T+N53BY*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N532T=0 N53BY=0
.PARAM N53NW= {N54AA+N55C1*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N54AA=0 N55C1=0
.PARAM N55SX=9.9280669986146
.PARAM N57ZV=12.221734790832
.PARAM N5AYG= {IF(N3FZZ(N57ZV,N4JCV,N4O9U,N4Q8J)>N3FZZ
+(N55SX,N4JCV,N4O9U,N4Q8J),N55SX,N57ZV)}
.PARAM N5B8N= {IF(N3FZZ(N57ZV,N4JCV,N4O9U,N4Q8J)>N3FZZ
+(N55SX,N4JCV,N4O9U,N4Q8J),N57ZV,N55SX)}
.PARAM N5BBA= {IF(N3FZZ(N57ZV,N4SVH,N4XP2,N53NW)>N3FZZ
+(N55SX,N4SVH,N4XP2,N53NW),N55SX,N57ZV)}
.PARAM N5CX8= {IF(N3FZZ(N57ZV,N4SVH,N4XP2,N53NW)>N3FZZ
+(N55SX,N4SVH,N4XP2,N53NW),N57ZV,N55SX)}
.PARAM N5G0G=1; 1==N5GVE N5H87,0==N5IP9 N5H87
.PARAM N5JG4=0; 1==N5KAP(N5KRE),0==N5KAP
.PARAM N5KAP= {N3DMO*N5L86} N5L86=9.7471837249841E-09
.PARAM N5LRV=1E-08
.PARAM N5LZX=0.0
.PARAM N5OHV= {N3DMO*N5P5D} N5P5D=5.83032018005204E-08
.PARAM N5QTE= {N3DMO*N5QX9} N5QX9=1.80377964241003E-09
.PARAM N5U1H=0.0166448596796836
.PARAM N5VOW=-0.415268531975957
.PARAM N6083=8.95548724354288E-10
.PARAM N61QP= {N3DMO*N62LV} N62LV=2.29921162369042E-09
.PARAM N63FK=2.50882653552144
.PARAM N63YW=-0.742795454737657
.PARAM N64FJ= {N6528+N676G*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N6528=5.34711151434077E-08
+N676G=4.48623408090115E-10
.PARAM N67W6=0.999665037354722
.PARAM N6F1G=1.666979169511E-08
.PARAM N6FLP=1E-10
.PARAM N6GH0= {N6JK1+N6R8Z*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N6JK1=2.91590674334133
+N6R8Z=0.0216094826762251
X1BKQ C G E E2 Z0LRC PARAMS: TJ= {TJ} N2Q22= {N2Q22} N3DMO= {N3DMO} KP= {KP}
+N3RWU= {N3RWU} N3TFE= {N3TFE} IS= {IS} N5KAP= {N5KAP} N5OHV= {N5OHV} N6083= {N6083}
+N6F1G= {N6F1G}
+N6FLP= {N6FLP} N6GH0= {N6GH0} N3WZE= {N3WZE} N40OC= {N40OC} N4A6Y= {N4A6Y}
+N4JCV= {N4JCV} N4O9U= {N4O9U} N4Q8J= {N4Q8J} N4SVH= {N4SVH} N4XP2= {N4XP2}
+N53NW= {N53NW} N5QTE= {N5QTE} N5U1H= {N5U1H} N5VOW= {N5VOW} N61QP= {N61QP}
+N63FK= {N63FK} N63YW= {N63YW} N64FJ= {N64FJ} N3PK5= {N3PK5} N67W6= {N67W6}
+N5LRV= {N5LRV} N5LZX= {N5LZX} N3PX3= {N3PX3} N3QEY= {N3QEY} N4JBQ= {N4JBQ}
+N5AYG= {N5AYG}
+N5B8N= {N5B8N} N5BBA= {N5BBA} N5CX8= {N5CX8} N5G0G= {N5G0G} N5JG4= {N5JG4}
.ENDS
 
.SUBCKT Z0D8I N2P16 C PARAMS: TJ= {TEMP} N2Q22=298.15 N2Q6O=0.0879
.PARAM N2QVM=4.06704260147118
.PARAM N2RKR= {N2Q6O*N2S9D*EXP((((TJ+273.15)/N2Q22)-1)*N2WU4)}
+N2S9D=0.000999999867172459 N2WU4=10.5695336055022
.PARAM N2X0Z= {(N2X9Y+N2Z0D*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22))/N2Q6O}
+N2X9Y=0.00204996548126675 N2Z0D=3.6027007375844E-06
.PARAM N30GC= {(N30QS+N31QY*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22))/N2Q6O}
+N30QS=0.000478279047793862 N31QY=1.00000270108895E-08
.PARAM N335J= {N36D1+N374S*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N36D1=2.43761366018101
+N374S=0.000423419715313354
.PARAM N3A5Q= {N3AD5+N3AXM*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N3AD5=2.3475750586066E-07
+N3AXM=1.34915783425592E-09
.PARAM N3B93= {N3DAA+N3DKM*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N3DAA=3.9937663385981E-07
+N3DKM=1.00133016737569E-09
X182M N2P16 C Z0MCW PARAMS: TJ= {TJ} N2Q22= {N2Q22} N2Q6O= {N2Q6O} N2QVM= {N2QVM}
+N2RKR= {N2RKR} N2X0Z= {N2X0Z} N30GC= {N30GC} N335J= {N335J} N3A5Q= {N3A5Q}
+N3B93= {N3B93}
.ENDS
 
.SUBCKT Z0FHA C G E E2 PARAMS: TJ= {TEMP} N2Q22=298.15 N3DMO=0.2759
.FUNC N3EZ7(N3FD9) {IF(N3FD9>=0,IF(N3FD9>50,(N3FD9-49)*EXP(50),EXP(N3FD9))
+,IF(ABS(N3FD9)>50,1/((ABS(N3FD9)-49)*EXP(50)),1/EXP(ABS(N3FD9))))}
.FUNC N3FZZ(N3HJN,N3HN7,N3IH2,N3J2Z) {N3HN7+N3IH2*N3EZ7(N3J2Z*N3HJN)}
.PARAM KP= {N3DMO*N3J3P*PWR((TJ+273.15)/N2Q22,-1.5)} N3J3P=98.0760199227401
.PARAM N3PK5= {N3PX3+N3QEY*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N3PX3=6.78023844942156 N3QEY=
+-0.00987903846464414
.PARAM N3RWU=4.12495904670812E-05
.PARAM N3TFE=3.83971039544805
.PARAM IS= {N3DMO*N3VRD*EXP((((TJ+273.15)/N2Q22)-1)*N3WF6)}
+N3VRD=0.000753849477958455 N3WF6=6.89684786048637
.PARAM N3WZE= {N3Z19+N3ZCX*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N3Z19=0.00879199568140942
+N3ZCX=6.48189291602807E-05
.PARAM N40OC= {N4585+N4A1X*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N4585=-8.2845101267526E-05
+N4A1X=4.11144827444856E-07
.PARAM N4A6Y= {N4DS3+N4IED*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N4DS3=2.87299864020962E-05
+N4IED=-5.14041349758208E-07
.PARAM N4JBQ=11.9947581072968
.PARAM N4JCV= {N4M0Q+N4M8G*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N4M0Q=0.00754980688227525 N4M8G=
+-9.07572051579079E-06
.PARAM N4O9U= {N4OJQ+N4OUJ*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N4OJQ=32.665759032316 N4OUJ=
+-0.998811663075804
.PARAM N4Q8J= {N4QGJ+N4RHB*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N4QGJ=-0.896814340457064
+N4RHB=0.00072340944815822
.PARAM N4SVH= {N4VI8+N4X8H*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N4VI8=4.19512562615542
+N4X8H=0.00988478436152999
.PARAM N4XP2= {N532T+N53BY*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N532T=0 N53BY=0
.PARAM N53NW= {N54AA+N55C1*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N54AA=0 N55C1=0
.PARAM N55SX=8.92838170892086
.PARAM N57ZV=18.5037575571587
.PARAM N5AYG= {IF(N3FZZ(N57ZV,N4JCV,N4O9U,N4Q8J)>N3FZZ
+(N55SX,N4JCV,N4O9U,N4Q8J),N55SX,N57ZV)}
.PARAM N5B8N= {IF(N3FZZ(N57ZV,N4JCV,N4O9U,N4Q8J)>N3FZZ
+(N55SX,N4JCV,N4O9U,N4Q8J),N57ZV,N55SX)}
.PARAM N5BBA= {IF(N3FZZ(N57ZV,N4SVH,N4XP2,N53NW)>N3FZZ
+(N55SX,N4SVH,N4XP2,N53NW),N55SX,N57ZV)}
.PARAM N5CX8= {IF(N3FZZ(N57ZV,N4SVH,N4XP2,N53NW)>N3FZZ
+(N55SX,N4SVH,N4XP2,N53NW),N57ZV,N55SX)}
.PARAM N5G0G=1; 1==N5GVE N5H87,0==N5IP9 N5H87
.PARAM N5JG4=0; 1==N5KAP(N5KRE),0==N5KAP
.PARAM N5KAP= {N3DMO*N5L86} N5L86=9.45299822135634E-09
.PARAM N5LRV=1E-08
.PARAM N5LZX=0.0
.PARAM N5OHV= {N3DMO*N5P5D} N5P5D=5.29954181710387E-08
.PARAM N5QTE= {N3DMO*N5QX9} N5QX9=1.78272897776685E-09
.PARAM N5U1H=0.150554504994607
.PARAM N5VOW=-0.44080758016708
.PARAM N6083=9.0468377654454E-09
.PARAM N61QP= {N3DMO*N62LV} N62LV=4.90414856244378E-09
.PARAM N63FK=4.87380340030086
.PARAM N63YW=-0.926240650275296
.PARAM N64FJ= {N6528+N676G*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N6528=9.97049921612043E-08
+N676G=2.37024276025351E-09
.PARAM N67W6=0.162518484640805
.PARAM N6F1G=1.33444398564753E-08
.PARAM N6FLP=1E-10
.PARAM N6GH0= {N6JK1+N6R8Z*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N6JK1=1.54566560142343
+N6R8Z=0.0179512023780066
X1BKQ C G E E2 Z0LRC PARAMS: TJ= {TJ} N2Q22= {N2Q22} N3DMO= {N3DMO} KP= {KP}
+N3RWU= {N3RWU} N3TFE= {N3TFE} IS= {IS} N5KAP= {N5KAP} N5OHV= {N5OHV} N6083= {N6083}
+N6F1G= {N6F1G}
+N6FLP= {N6FLP} N6GH0= {N6GH0} N3WZE= {N3WZE} N40OC= {N40OC} N4A6Y= {N4A6Y}
+N4JCV= {N4JCV} N4O9U= {N4O9U} N4Q8J= {N4Q8J} N4SVH= {N4SVH} N4XP2= {N4XP2}
+N53NW= {N53NW} N5QTE= {N5QTE} N5U1H= {N5U1H} N5VOW= {N5VOW} N61QP= {N61QP}
+N63FK= {N63FK} N63YW= {N63YW} N64FJ= {N64FJ} N3PK5= {N3PK5} N67W6= {N67W6}
+N5LRV= {N5LRV} N5LZX= {N5LZX} N3PX3= {N3PX3} N3QEY= {N3QEY} N4JBQ= {N4JBQ}
+N5AYG= {N5AYG}
+N5B8N= {N5B8N} N5BBA= {N5BBA} N5CX8= {N5CX8} N5G0G= {N5G0G} N5JG4= {N5JG4}
.ENDS
 
.SUBCKT Z0G0T N2P16 C PARAMS: TJ= {TEMP} N2Q22=298.15 N2Q6O=0.0879
.PARAM N2QVM=4.06704260147118
.PARAM N2RKR= {N2Q6O*N2S9D*EXP((((TJ+273.15)/N2Q22)-1)*N2WU4)}
+N2S9D=0.000999999867172459 N2WU4=10.5695336055022
.PARAM N2X0Z= {(N2X9Y+N2Z0D*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22))/N2Q6O}
+N2X9Y=0.00204996548126675 N2Z0D=3.6027007375844E-06
.PARAM N30GC= {(N30QS+N31QY*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22))/N2Q6O}
+N30QS=0.000478279047793862 N31QY=1.00000270108895E-08
.PARAM N335J= {N36D1+N374S*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N36D1=2.43761366018101
+N374S=0.000423419715313355
.PARAM N3A5Q= {N3AD5+N3AXM*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N3AD5=1.45430858284018E-07
+N3AXM=7.35387856449882E-10
.PARAM N3B93= {N3DAA+N3DKM*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N3DAA=1.04910630184141E-07
+N3DKM=2.76240708080442E-10
X182M N2P16 C Z0MCW PARAMS: TJ= {TJ} N2Q22= {N2Q22} N2Q6O= {N2Q6O} N2QVM= {N2QVM}
+N2RKR= {N2RKR} N2X0Z= {N2X0Z} N30GC= {N30GC} N335J= {N335J} N3A5Q= {N3A5Q}
+N3B93= {N3B93}
.ENDS
 
.SUBCKT Z0G3A C G E E2 PARAMS: TJ= {TEMP} N2Q22=298.15 N3DMO=0.2759
.FUNC N3EZ7(N3FD9) {IF(N3FD9>=0,IF(N3FD9>50,(N3FD9-49)*EXP(50),EXP(N3FD9))
+,IF(ABS(N3FD9)>50,1/((ABS(N3FD9)-49)*EXP(50)),1/EXP(ABS(N3FD9))))}
.FUNC N3FZZ(N3HJN,N3HN7,N3IH2,N3J2Z) {N3HN7+N3IH2*N3EZ7(N3J2Z*N3HJN)}
.PARAM KP= {N3DMO*N3J3P*PWR((TJ+273.15)/N2Q22,-1.5)} N3J3P=98.0760199227401
.PARAM N3PK5= {N3PX3+N3QEY*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N3PX3=6.78023844942156 N3QEY=
+-0.00999878847427108
.PARAM N3RWU=4.12495904670813E-05
.PARAM N3TFE=3.83971039544805
.PARAM IS= {N3DMO*N3VRD*EXP((((TJ+273.15)/N2Q22)-1)*N3WF6)}
+N3VRD=0.000753849477958455 N3WF6=6.84937427012716
.PARAM N3WZE= {N3Z19+N3ZCX*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N3Z19=0.00879199568140942
+N3ZCX=7.24056021771799E-05
.PARAM N40OC= {N4585+N4A1X*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N4585=-8.2845101267526E-05
+N4A1X=9.00798620197426E-07
.PARAM N4A6Y= {N4DS3+N4IED*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N4DS3=2.87299864020962E-05
+N4IED=-9.17268256399645E-07
.PARAM N4JBQ=11.9947581072968
.PARAM N4JCV= {N4M0Q+N4M8G*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N4M0Q=0.00754980688227525 N4M8G=
+-7.32942262066994E-06
.PARAM N4O9U= {N4OJQ+N4OUJ*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N4OJQ=32.665759032316 N4OUJ=
+-0.9999117939858
.PARAM N4Q8J= {N4QGJ+N4RHB*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N4QGJ=-0.896814340457064
+N4RHB=0.000751123775316505
.PARAM N4SVH= {N4VI8+N4X8H*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N4VI8=4.19512562615542
+N4X8H=0.00999372467548881
.PARAM N4XP2= {N532T+N53BY*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N532T=0 N53BY=0
.PARAM N53NW= {N54AA+N55C1*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N54AA=0 N55C1=0
.PARAM N55SX=8.92838170892086
.PARAM N57ZV=18.5037575571587
.PARAM N5AYG= {IF(N3FZZ(N57ZV,N4JCV,N4O9U,N4Q8J)>N3FZZ
+(N55SX,N4JCV,N4O9U,N4Q8J),N55SX,N57ZV)}
.PARAM N5B8N= {IF(N3FZZ(N57ZV,N4JCV,N4O9U,N4Q8J)>N3FZZ
+(N55SX,N4JCV,N4O9U,N4Q8J),N57ZV,N55SX)}
.PARAM N5BBA= {IF(N3FZZ(N57ZV,N4SVH,N4XP2,N53NW)>N3FZZ
+(N55SX,N4SVH,N4XP2,N53NW),N55SX,N57ZV)}
.PARAM N5CX8= {IF(N3FZZ(N57ZV,N4SVH,N4XP2,N53NW)>N3FZZ
+(N55SX,N4SVH,N4XP2,N53NW),N57ZV,N55SX)}
.PARAM N5G0G=1; 1==N5GVE N5H87,0==N5IP9 N5H87
.PARAM N5JG4=0; 1==N5KAP(N5KRE),0==N5KAP
.PARAM N5KAP= {N3DMO*N5L86} N5L86=9.45316847110016E-09
.PARAM N5LRV=1E-08
.PARAM N5LZX=0.0
.PARAM N5OHV= {N3DMO*N5P5D} N5P5D=5.52618638927975E-08
.PARAM N5QTE= {N3DMO*N5QX9} N5QX9=1.756195384588E-09
.PARAM N5U1H=0.135325183281542
.PARAM N5VOW=-0.432094995061983
.PARAM N6083=1.03303176184083E-08
.PARAM N61QP= {N3DMO*N62LV} N62LV=4.7061209341045E-09
.PARAM N63FK=4.58560127245578
.PARAM N63YW=-0.919591616526291
.PARAM N64FJ= {N6528+N676G*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N6528=4.38596165483836E-08
+N676G=2.77457431946279E-10
.PARAM N67W6=0.999962343993092
.PARAM N6F1G=1.3E-08
.PARAM N6FLP=2.29172593782846E-09
.PARAM N6GH0= {N6JK1+N6R8Z*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N6JK1=2.46527686071165
+N6R8Z=0.0166118702357128
X1BKQ C G E E2 Z0LRC PARAMS: TJ= {TJ} N2Q22= {N2Q22} N3DMO= {N3DMO} KP= {KP}
+N3RWU= {N3RWU} N3TFE= {N3TFE} IS= {IS} N5KAP= {N5KAP} N5OHV= {N5OHV} N6083= {N6083}
+N6F1G= {N6F1G}
+N6FLP= {N6FLP} N6GH0= {N6GH0} N3WZE= {N3WZE} N40OC= {N40OC} N4A6Y= {N4A6Y}
+N4JCV= {N4JCV} N4O9U= {N4O9U} N4Q8J= {N4Q8J} N4SVH= {N4SVH} N4XP2= {N4XP2}
+N53NW= {N53NW} N5QTE= {N5QTE} N5U1H= {N5U1H} N5VOW= {N5VOW} N61QP= {N61QP}
+N63FK= {N63FK} N63YW= {N63YW} N64FJ= {N64FJ} N3PK5= {N3PK5} N67W6= {N67W6}
+N5LRV= {N5LRV} N5LZX= {N5LZX} N3PX3= {N3PX3} N3QEY= {N3QEY} N4JBQ= {N4JBQ}
+N5AYG= {N5AYG}
+N5B8N= {N5B8N} N5BBA= {N5BBA} N5CX8= {N5CX8} N5G0G= {N5G0G} N5JG4= {N5JG4}
.ENDS
 
.SUBCKT Z0JVB N2P16 C PARAMS: TJ= {TEMP} N2Q22=298.15 N2Q6O=0.2
.PARAM N2QVM=3.68537638571323
.PARAM N2RKR= {N2Q6O*N2S9D*EXP((((TJ+273.15)/N2Q22)-1)*N2WU4)}
+N2S9D=0.000545731707365698 N2WU4=10.8145146299573
.PARAM N2X0Z= {(N2X9Y+N2Z0D*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22))/N2Q6O}
+N2X9Y=0.0023509875843126 N2Z0D=4.15570427030393E-06
.PARAM N30GC= {(N30QS+N31QY*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22))/N2Q6O}
+N30QS=0.000956825407703397 N31QY=1.07434161520714E-07
.PARAM N335J= {N36D1+N374S*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N36D1=3.00027038260557
+N374S=0.000872325050804337
.PARAM N3A5Q= {N3AD5+N3AXM*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N3AD5=1.42199276036729E-07
+N3AXM=9.72032983661442E-10
.PARAM N3B93= {N3DAA+N3DKM*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N3DAA=8.4336833968339E-08
+N3DKM=3.16320191916364E-10
X182M N2P16 C Z0MCW PARAMS: TJ= {TJ} N2Q22= {N2Q22} N2Q6O= {N2Q6O} N2QVM= {N2QVM}
+N2RKR= {N2RKR} N2X0Z= {N2X0Z} N30GC= {N30GC} N335J= {N335J} N3A5Q= {N3A5Q}
+N3B93= {N3B93}
.ENDS
 
.SUBCKT Z0KYD C G E E2 PARAMS: TJ= {TEMP} N2Q22=298.15 N3DMO=0.5167
.FUNC N3EZ7(N3FD9) {IF(N3FD9>=0,IF(N3FD9>50,(N3FD9-49)*EXP(50),EXP(N3FD9))
+,IF(ABS(N3FD9)>50,1/((ABS(N3FD9)-49)*EXP(50)),1/EXP(ABS(N3FD9))))}
.FUNC N3FZZ(N3HJN,N3HN7,N3IH2,N3J2Z) {N3HN7+N3IH2*N3EZ7(N3J2Z*N3HJN)}
.PARAM KP= {N3DMO*N3J3P*PWR((TJ+273.15)/N2Q22,-1.5)} N3J3P=121.181031811671
.PARAM N3PK5= {N3PX3+N3QEY*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N3PX3=6.57832738518404 N3QEY=
+-0.00459465568592502
.PARAM N3RWU=0.000336706133311952
.PARAM N3TFE=3.96129026572307
.PARAM IS= {N3DMO*N3VRD*EXP((((TJ+273.15)/N2Q22)-1)*N3WF6)}
+N3VRD=0.000655252047247131 N3WF6=7.39611745789556
.PARAM N3WZE= {N3Z19+N3ZCX*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N3Z19=0.00846867271115328
+N3ZCX=6.21415604263307E-06
.PARAM N40OC= {N4585+N4A1X*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N4585=-9.38595887345843E-05
+N4A1X=7.25888939429805E-07
.PARAM N4A6Y= {N4DS3+N4IED*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N4DS3=-5.33717740854242E-05
+N4IED=3.48043140078913E-07
.PARAM N4JBQ=11.9873077437673
.PARAM N4JCV= {N4M0Q+N4M8G*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N4M0Q=0.00368567314612722 N4M8G=
+-6.21589338384407E-06
.PARAM N4O9U= {N4OJQ+N4OUJ*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N4OJQ=-80.2151001281395
+N4OUJ=0.527454027455842
.PARAM N4Q8J= {N4QGJ+N4RHB*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N4QGJ=-0.99922291890718
+N4RHB=0.0031915711534846
.PARAM N4SVH= {N4VI8+N4X8H*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N4VI8=2.90829502701543
+N4X8H=0.00987611334910169
.PARAM N4XP2= {N532T+N53BY*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N532T=0 N53BY=0
.PARAM N53NW= {N54AA+N55C1*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N54AA=0 N55C1=0
.PARAM N55SX=6.20520606065892
.PARAM N57ZV=12.8423891797406
.PARAM N5AYG= {IF(N3FZZ(N57ZV,N4JCV,N4O9U,N4Q8J)>N3FZZ
+(N55SX,N4JCV,N4O9U,N4Q8J),N55SX,N57ZV)}
.PARAM N5B8N= {IF(N3FZZ(N57ZV,N4JCV,N4O9U,N4Q8J)>N3FZZ
+(N55SX,N4JCV,N4O9U,N4Q8J),N57ZV,N55SX)}
.PARAM N5BBA= {IF(N3FZZ(N57ZV,N4SVH,N4XP2,N53NW)>N3FZZ
+(N55SX,N4SVH,N4XP2,N53NW),N55SX,N57ZV)}
.PARAM N5CX8= {IF(N3FZZ(N57ZV,N4SVH,N4XP2,N53NW)>N3FZZ
+(N55SX,N4SVH,N4XP2,N53NW),N57ZV,N55SX)}
.PARAM N5G0G=1; 1==N5GVE N5H87,0==N5IP9 N5H87
.PARAM N5JG4=0; 1==N5KAP(N5KRE),0==N5KAP
.PARAM N5KAP= {N3DMO*N5L86} N5L86=9.02737697776395E-09
.PARAM N5LRV=1E-08
.PARAM N5LZX=0.0
.PARAM N5OHV= {N3DMO*N5P5D} N5P5D=5.55521530186442E-08
.PARAM N5QTE= {N3DMO*N5QX9} N5QX9=1.77150294535545E-09
.PARAM N5U1H=0.071800677113438
.PARAM N5VOW=-0.43165812676055
.PARAM N6083=1.82830423803902E-09
.PARAM N61QP= {N3DMO*N62LV} N62LV=4.477732001274E-09
.PARAM N63FK=4.26375975298938
.PARAM N63YW=-0.890942489892027
.PARAM N64FJ= {N6528+N676G*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N6528=3.3907663267538E-08
+N676G=2.23235327147193E-10
.PARAM N67W6=0.995142932632205
.PARAM N6F1G=1.3E-08
.PARAM N6FLP=1.36286591933986E-09
.PARAM N6GH0= {N6JK1+N6R8Z*(TJ+273.15-N2Q22)} N6JK1=2.83758929592012
+N6R8Z=0.000106388310408014
X1BKQ C G E E2 Z0LRC PARAMS: TJ= {TJ} N2Q22= {N2Q22} N3DMO= {N3DMO} KP= {KP}
+N3RWU= {N3RWU} N3TFE= {N3TFE} IS= {IS} N5KAP= {N5KAP} N5OHV= {N5OHV} N6083= {N6083}
+N6F1G= {N6F1G}
+N6FLP= {N6FLP} N6GH0= {N6GH0} N3WZE= {N3WZE} N40OC= {N40OC} N4A6Y= {N4A6Y}
+N4JCV= {N4JCV} N4O9U= {N4O9U} N4Q8J= {N4Q8J} N4SVH= {N4SVH} N4XP2= {N4XP2}
+N53NW= {N53NW} N5QTE= {N5QTE} N5U1H= {N5U1H} N5VOW= {N5VOW} N61QP= {N61QP}
+N63FK= {N63FK} N63YW= {N63YW} N64FJ= {N64FJ} N3PK5= {N3PK5} N67W6= {N67W6}
+N5LRV= {N5LRV} N5LZX= {N5LZX} N3PX3= {N3PX3} N3QEY= {N3QEY} N4JBQ= {N4JBQ}
+N5AYG= {N5AYG}
+N5B8N= {N5B8N} N5BBA= {N5BBA} N5CX8= {N5CX8} N5G0G= {N5G0G} N5JG4= {N5JG4}
.ENDS
 
.SUBCKT Z0LRC C G E E2 PARAMS: TJ= {1} N2Q22= {1} N3DMO= {1} KP= {1} N3RWU= {1} N3TFE= {1}
+IS= {1} N5KAP= {1} N5OHV= {1} N6083= {1} N6F1G= {1} N6FLP= {1} N6GH0= {1}
+N3WZE= {1} N40OC= {1} N4A6Y= {1} N4JCV= {1} N4O9U= {1} N4Q8J= {1} N4SVH= {1} N4XP2= {1}
+N53NW= {1} N5QTE= {1} N5U1H= {1} N5VOW= {1} N61QP= {1} N63FK= {1} N63YW= {1} N64FJ= {1}
+N3PK5= {1} N67W6= {1}
+N5LRV= {1} N5LZX= {1} N3PX3= {1} N3QEY= {1} N4JBQ= {1} N5AYG= {1} N5B8N= {1} N5BBA= {1}
+N5CX8= {1} N5G0G= {1} N5JG4= {1}
.FUNC N3EZ7(N3FD9) {IF(N3FD9>=0,IF(N3FD9>50,(N3FD9-49)*EXP(50),EXP(N3FD9))
+,IF(ABS(N3FD9)>50,1/((ABS(N3FD9)-49)*EXP(50)),1/EXP(ABS(N3FD9))))}
.FUNC N6RMM(N3FD9) {(1-N3EZ7(-2*N3FD9))/(1+N3EZ7(-2*N3FD9))}
.FUNC N6UER(N3FD9) {0.5*(N3EZ7(N3FD9)+N3EZ7(-N3FD9))}
.FUNC N6USE(N3HJN,N3HN7,N3IH2,N3J2Z) {N3HN7+N3IH2*N3HJN+N3J2Z*PWR(N3HJN,2)}
.FUNC N3FZZ(N3HJN,N3HN7,N3IH2,N3J2Z) {N3HN7+N3IH2*N3EZ7(N3J2Z*N3HJN)}
.FUNC N6VEA(N3HJN,N3HN7) {N3HN7*N3HJN}
.FUNC N6ZE0(N3HJN,N3HN7,N3IH2,N3J2Z) {(N3HN7*PWR(N3IH2+N3HJN,N3J2Z+1))/
+(N3J2Z+1)}
.FUNC N6ZQA(N3HJN,N3HN7,N3IH2,N3J2Z) {N3HN7*LOG10(MAX(N3IH2+N3HJN,1E-2))
++N3J2Z*N3HJN}
.PARAM N716Z=1.3806E-23
.PARAM N73UU=1.6022E-19
.MODEL N77CQ NMOS(KP= {KP} VTO= {N3PK5} LAMBDA= {N3RWU} TNOM= {TJ} T_ABS= {TJ})
M1JO6 2 N77PO 1 1 N77CQ
.MODEL N7DGV D(N= {N3TFE} IS= {IS} TNOM= {TJ} T_ABS= {TJ})
D1JYW 5 4 N7DGV
.FUNC N7DI6(N3HJN,N3WZE,N40OC,N4A6Y) {MAX(MIN(N6USE(N3HJN,N3WZE,N40OC,N4A6Y)
+,
+N6USE(N4JBQ,N3WZE,N40OC,N4A6Y)),
+N6USE(N3PX3+N3QEY*(175+273.15-N2Q22),N3WZE,N40OC,N4A6Y))}
E1KOR 1 N7FFI VALUE= {I(V1Z54)*N7DI6(V(N77PO,E),N3WZE,N40OC,N4A6Y)}
.FUNC N7G6Y(N7GBN,N5KRE,N4SVH,N4XP2,N53NW,N4JCV,N4O9U,N4Q8J) {(1-(1/(N3EZ7
+(N7GBN-N7GNX(N5KRE,N4SVH,N4XP2,N53NW))+1)))*N7GSE
+(N5KRE,N4JCV,N4O9U,N4Q8J)}
.FUNC N7GSE(N3HJN,N4JCV,N4O9U,N4Q8J) {MAX(MIN(N3FZZ(N3HJN,N4JCV,N4O9U,N4Q8J)
+,N3FZZ(N5B8N,N4JCV,N4O9U,N4Q8J)),N3FZZ(N5AYG,N4JCV,N4O9U,N4Q8J))}
.FUNC N7GNX(N3HJN,N4SVH,N4XP2,N53NW) {MAX(MIN(N3FZZ(N3HJN,N4SVH,N4XP2,N53NW)
+,N3FZZ(N5CX8,N4SVH,N4XP2,N53NW)),N3FZZ(N5BBA,N4SVH,N4XP2,N53NW))}
E1L63 2 3 VALUE= {I(V1Z54)*N7G6Y(V(C,E),V(N77PO,E)
+,N4SVH,N4XP2,N53NW,N4JCV,N4O9U,N4Q8J)}
.FUNC N7IU1(N3HJN,N5KAP,N5LZX,N5LRV) {IF(N5JG4==1,MIN(N3HJN-N5LZX-(1/N5KAP)*
+(N6VEA(N3HJN,N5LRV)-N6VEA(-N3HJN,N5LRV)),0),0)}
.FUNC N7K96(N3HJN,N5OHV,N5QTE,N5U1H,N5VOW) {IF(N5G0G==1,
+MAX(N3HJN-(1/N5OHV)*(N6ZE0(N3HJN,N5QTE,N5U1H,N5VOW)-N6ZE0
+(0,N5QTE,N5U1H,N5VOW)),0),
+MAX(N3HJN-(1/N5OHV)*(N6ZQA(N3HJN,N5QTE,N5U1H,N5VOW)-N6ZQA
+(0,N5QTE,N5U1H,N5VOW)),0))}
.FUNC N7KF6(N3HJN,N6083,N61QP,N63FK,N63YW) {IF(N5G0G==1,
+MAX(N3HJN-(1/N6083)*(N6ZE0(N3HJN,N61QP,N63FK,N63YW)-N6ZE0
+(0,N61QP,N63FK,N63YW)),0),
+MAX(N3HJN-(1/N6083)*(N6ZQA(N3HJN,N61QP,N63FK,N63YW)-N6ZQA
+(0,N61QP,N63FK,N63YW)),0))}
C1MO4 N7FFI 15  {N5KAP}
C1PY9 6 13  {N5OHV}
C1Q03 7 14  {N6083}
E1QAJ 15 N77PO VALUE= {N7IU1(V(N7FFI,N77PO),N5KAP,N5LZX,N5LRV)}
E1QZ0 6 N77PO VALUE= {N7K96(MAX(V(C,N77PO),0),N5OHV,N5QTE,N5U1H,N5VOW)}
E1RME 7 N7FFI VALUE= {N7KF6(MAX(V(C,N7FFI),0),N6083,N61QP,N63FK,N63YW)}
R1SRX 13 5  {10E-3}
R1UKD 14 5  {100}
G1UXF 5 11 VALUE= {MAX(ABS(I(V1ZKQ))-ABS(I(V21CK)),0)}
G1WZ9 0 10 VALUE= {ABS(I(V1Z54))*N67W6}
G1XBA 8 9 VALUE= {(V(8,0)*1E-6)/N64FJ}
C1XZT 0 8  {1E-6}
L1YH9 E E2  {N6F1G}
L1YP8 E2 N7FFI  {N6FLP}
G1YZR N7L99 N77PO VALUE= {V(N7L99,N77PO)/N6GH0}
V1Z54 4 3  {0}
V1ZHQ C 5  {0}
V1ZKQ 9 0  {0}
V21CK 10 8  {0}
V2433 11 N7FFI  {0}
V24YY G N7L99  {0}
R25DW 5 0  {100E6}
R25F8 15 N7FFI  {100E6}
R266N 6 N77PO  {100E6}
R26MB 7 N7FFI  {100E6}
R28G6 8 0  {100E6}
R2AQK E N7FFI  {100E6}
.ENDS
 
.SUBCKT Z0MCW N2P16 C PARAMS: TJ= {1} N2Q22= {1} N2Q6O= {1} N2QVM= {1} N2RKR= {1}
+N2X0Z= {1} N30GC= {1} N335J= {1} N3A5Q= {1} N3B93= {1}
.FUNC N7LG5(N3FD9) {IF(N3FD9>=0,IF(N3FD9>50,(N3FD9-49)*EXP(50),EXP(N3FD9))
+,IF(ABS(N3FD9)>50,1/((ABS(N3FD9)-49)*EXP(50)),1/EXP(ABS(N3FD9))))}
.FUNC N7NVG(N3FD9) {(1-N7LG5(-2*N3FD9))/(1+N7LG5(-2*N3FD9))}
.MODEL N7OGC D(N= {N2QVM} IS= {N2RKR} TNOM= {TJ} T_ABS= {TJ})
D2B1N N7OIA N7Q2N N7OGC
.FUNC N7Q94(N7QQO) {(1-((N7NVG(N7QQO*N30GC))/N335J))*N2X0Z}
E2B9S N7Q2N C VALUE= {I(V2JL7)*N7Q94(I(V2JL7))}
G2CAL N2P16 N7RTQ VALUE= {(I(V2JL7)*N3A5Q-V(N7S12,0)*1E-6)/N3B93}
G2CN5 0 N7S12 VALUE= {I(V2JL7)-I(V2KU7)}
G2GOD N7S12 0 VALUE= {(V(N7S12,0)*1E-6)/N3A5Q}
C2HUV N7S12 0  {1E-6}
V2JL7 N2P16 N7OIA  {0}
V2KU7 N7Q2N N7RTQ  {0}
R2M6H N7OIA N7Q2N  {100E6}
R2O8J N7OIA 0  {100E6}
R2ORF N7S12 0  {100E6}
.ENDS
```
````

Comment: You seem to be asking for a procedure to take a datasheet, with all of its limitations, and to then generate a Spice model for it. And you propose to offer a Spice model for something else as a guide? Tektronix used to sell an entire line (STS -- their semiconductor test systems division) of expensive tools just for this purpose. You'd plug in a device and it would spit out a model for you after a lot of interesting test results are collected.

Comment: Although someone here may actually want to take this on, I'm certainly not that person. One might also be able to 'shoot from the hip' on this, comparing two datasheets. But all I can offer are my best wishes. I'd read what someone else wrote here and learn from that. But I'm not able to take time to consider this, myself.

Comment: This seems to have cut off the copyright or download notice.  I looked it up, and, I guess they don't have a "don't distribute without this notice" clause, but I don't know offhand if that should be assumed anyway. The download link might be preferable?

Comment: What do you use the SPICE models to evaluate in your experiments? If you're just interested in the thermal modeling, you can probably adapt the PLECS model to be used in LTspice. Otherwise, I think it might be better to produce your own models instead of trying to reverse engineer the previous Infineon models. First step of that would be to understand how the built-in LTspice IGBT works, which is [defined in this paper by Hefner](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0038110188900251). Also worth noting is this thread: https://groups.io/g/LTspice/topic/igbt_model/82753066